# How to clear material UI textfield with webdriver

Tags: webdriver, material-ui

please I have problem that i am not able to clear text which is in Material-Ui text field.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("CompanyNameField")).clear();
```

will clear the field, but when switching to another tab with

```
driver.findElement(By.id("CompanyNameField")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB)
```

will cause that value previously cleared is back in text field.

Please any ideas how to clear this field permanently?
Thanks

Comment: does it happen when you manually clear the text and use tag to navigate to different text field?

Comment: hello. no it does not. It seems that clear does not fire event to component

Comment: what do you mean by it does not fire event to component. you are able to see fields getting cleared after the first line, aren't you? try putting some wait between two lines and then check.

Comment: I did. But when I am trying even to getText from element i got value={char[0]@4280}
Honestly i didn't get it at all. I am pretty newbie with webdriver adn coding at all.
Probably I have ask devs whats going on here. Anyway, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sending backspace keys to the form worked for me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cssSelector)
for _ in element.get_attribute('value'):
    element.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```